# Css width issue with zooming

Tags: jquery, html, css

is there any elegant way of stretching a div to the entire html, rather than the viewport?
http://pastebin.com/iU6e92xy
whenever you zoom and horizontal scrollbars appear, the 'test' div only extends to the initial viewport.

Now i am using jquery to acchieve the effect

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#test').css('min-width',$(document).width()+'px');
});
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work for you:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#test').css('minWidth', windowWidth); 
});
```

Comment: isn't there any way of doing it in plain old css, rather that use javascript for reaching my purpose? Actually, $(window).width is the width of the viewport, not of the page.

Comment: And also, the css property is min-width not minWidth.

Comment: in jQuery, that's how you write CSS. You cannot have the '-' symbol. So for example, `background-color` would be `backgroundColor`.

Comment: actually jquery accepts both. But still, my code works better than yours. So what about plain old css?